# How to convert a markdown blockquote using `markdown` parser into `BeautifulSoup` html blockquote?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, markdown

I am trying to convert markdown to html.

I created this function. It takes in a markdown string, and returns a html string.

```py
def markdown_to_html(text):
    extensions = [
        'extra',
        'abbr',
        'attr_list',
        'def_list',
        'fenced_code',
        'footnotes',
        'md_in_html',
        'admonition',
        'codehilite',
        'legacy_attrs',
        'legacy_em',
        'meta',
        'nl2br',
        'sane_lists',
        'smarty',
        'toc',
        'wikilinks'
    ]
    md = markdown.markdown(text, extensions=extensions)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(md, features='html.parser')
    html = print_to_string(soup.prettify())
    return html
```

This works for nearly all markdown codes. It successfully converts *italics*, **bold**, and bullet points. However I can't get it to convert blockquotes `>`. It seems that `html.parser` is just nor capable for it.

I tried to use `markdown.parser` instead, but it gave me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_to_html.py", line 252, in <module>
    main()
  File "json_to_html.py", line 231, in main
    article_html_text = markdown_to_html(article_text)
  File "json_to_html.py", line 177, in markdown_to_html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(md, features='markdown.parser')
  File "/home/konstantin/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 251, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: markdown.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Comment: I don't think beautifulsoup works with any parsers other than `html`/`lxml`/`xml`/`html5lib` so you can't just set it to `markdown.parser`, but just `html.parser` [should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7zhv.png) anyway - can you show us some input `text` that it did not work with?

Comment: The new name is `md_in_html` now.

Comment: So.. to clarify, the question is .. **"how to parse a markdown blockquote into an html blockquote?** Is that correct? If yes, there is some nuanced behaviour with blockquote  parsing see: https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/issues/1342 . Either way, its easier to see what's wrong with an example of (i) your `markdown blockquote` (input) and (ii) your currently parsed (but incorrect) html output.